# Combining two list, only records with 1 specific unique property

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm combining two lists in visual basic. These lists are of a custom object. The only record I want to combine, are the once with a property doesn't match with any other object in the list so far. I've got it running. However, the first list is just 1.247 records. The second list however, is just short of 27.000.000 records. The last time I successfully merged the two list with this restriction, it took over 5 hours.

Usually I code in C#. I've had a similar problem there once, and solved it with the any function. It worked perfectly and really fast. So as you can see in the code, I tried that here too. However it takes way too long.

```
Private Function combineLists(list As List(Of Record), childrenlist As List(Of Record)) As List(Of Record) 'list is about 1.250 entries, childrenlist about 27.000.000
    For Each r As Record In childrenlist
        Dim dublicate As Boolean = list.Any(Function(record) record.materiaalnummerInfo = r.materiaalnummerInfo)
        If Not dublicate Then
            list.Add(r)
        End If

    Next

    Return list
End Function
```

The object Record looks like this ( I wasn't sure how to make a custom object in VB, and this looks bad, but it worked):

```
Public Class Record
    Dim materiaalnummer As String
    Dim type As String 'Config or prefered
    Dim materiaalstatus As String
    Dim children As New List(Of String)

    Public Property materiaalnummerInfo()
        Get
            Return materiaalnummer
        End Get
        Set(value)
            materiaalnummer = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property typeInfo()
        Get
            Return type
        End Get
        Set(value)
            type = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property materiaalstatusInfo()
        Get
            Return materiaalstatus
        End Get
        Set(value)
            materiaalstatus = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property childrenInfo()
        Get
            Return children
        End Get
        Set(value)
            children = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction to shorten the time needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any update? Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want the output to be such as all differences or just ones from the larger list etc but I would definitely try do it with LINQ! Basically sql for vb.net data so would something similar to this:

```
Dim differenceQuery = list.Except(childrenlist)  
        Console.WriteLine("The following lines are in list  but not childrenlist")  

        ' Execute the query.  
        For Each name As String In differenceQuery  
            Console.WriteLine(name)  
        Next
```

Also side-note i would suggest not calling one of the lists "list" as it is bad practice and is a in use name on the vb.net system

**EDIT**

Please try this then let me know what results come back.

```
 Private Function combineLists(list As List(Of Record), childrenlist As List(Of Record)) As List(Of Record) 'list is about 1.250 entries, childrenlist about 27.000.000

        list.AddRange(childrenlist) 'combines both lists

        Dim result = From v In list Select v.materiaalnummerInfo Distinct.ToList
'result hopefully may be a list with all distinct values.

    End Function
```

Or Don't combine them if you dont want to.

Comment: Thank you for your responce. Because of the second, third and fourth parameters of the objects, I can't use the except function. However, I do thing I think I can solve the issues with other Linq functions. Unfortunately I'm not the best with SQL, so it takes some time to figure it out for me.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure as to what you mean by other parameters, maybe if you could provide a small sample of data, and small expected output i should be able to help better!

Comment: I just updated the question, where it now shows what the object Record looks like.

Comment: Okay i'm still a little confused as you say it needs to satisfy other parameters yet the above example you provided in your question you only look at `materiaalnummerInfo` ? Could distinct work? Where you quickly join the 2 lists by `list.addRange(childrenList)` then use LINQ `.Distinct().ToList()` ? I apologize for perhaps giving a wrong answer again I'm doing my best to understand what you are asking etc.

Comment: As you can see, every object got 4 parameters, where 3 are a String and 1 is a List. The first one, 'materiaalnummer' is the one that I  check. If there's no record in the list with matching 'materiaalnummer' yet, then copy the object to that list and go to next record. If there already is a record with that 'materiaalnummer', then directly go to the next record without copying.

Comment: I think I was unclear, sorry about that. English isn't my first language and sometimes I struggle with it.
The value of 'type','materiaalstatus' and 'children' are irrelevant while determining whether the record needs to be copied or not. In fact, when I check the records, those three values will be _null_. I did not find how to use distinct on a list, when I'm only checking for one of the four parameters of said item. If there's a way but I just missed it, I'd be happy to use that one, since it seems to be the one that makes the most sense.

Comment: No problem at all, just trying my best to understand and help you. See edit above.

Comment: Hello K.Madden,

I found a solution to my problem.

In stead of making a record out of every child like, I first make a list of String, on which I later use the List.Distinct().ToList() function. I didn't include this part of the code, because I didn't think there would be the solution.

I'd like to thank you for your help. You pointing me towards the LINQ is what made this possible. In stead of 5 hours for the first iteration, I now only need 80 seconds.